# Agrupar colunas com o framework Bulma CSS

Tags: css, bulma, columns

Gostaria de criar o seguinte layout utilizando o framework Bulma CSS.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

estou com o seguinte código.

```
<div class="columns">
    <div class="column is-2">AQUI</div>
    <div class="column is-2"></div>
    <div class="column is-2"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="columns">
    <div class="column is-2">AQUI</div>
    <div class="column is-2"></div>
    <div class="column is-2"></div>
  </div>
```

como faço para as duas colunas com o nome `AQUI` serem uma só? verticalmente?
para que fique igual a imagem?

estou olhando a documentação do framework, mas não estou conseguindo.

Comment: É possível com essa estrutura ou vc apenas não está conseguindo?

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que assim te atenda

```
<div class="columns"> 
    <div class="column">
      Primeira coluna
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <div class="column">
        Segunda
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        E terceira
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="column">
          Segunda
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          E terceira
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Na versão que uso do bulma essa forma funcionou bem. Coloquei os "
" para imitar o contexto.
Porem acho que tem outras formas interessantes para fazer sem usar o comlumns.
Caso tenha interesse fazer de outra forma diz-me que monto um exemplo.

```
<div class="columns is-multiline">

  <div class="column has-background-info">
    <div class="columns">
      Primeira coluna
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="column has-background-info">
      Segunda
      <br>
      <br>
      <br><br>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="column has-background-info">
      Segunda
      <br>
      <br><br>
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="column has-background-info">
      Terceira
      <br><br><br><br>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="column has-background-info">
      Terceira
      <br><br><br>
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Coloquei na sandbox:
https://codepen.io/nelloe86/pen/JjKREKp